# Подскажите сервер IRC для программистов

Tags: irc

Есть желание пообщаться с программистами в IRC, интересующие тематики: веб-разработка и С++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так подключайтесь к Rusnet'u там много комнат где говорят на такие темы :-)
 #cpp, #web, #coding etc

Answer (score 2):

DalNet - там на русском.

Comment: мертва сеть? мне бы русскую какуюнибудь подскажите где много юзеров общаеца

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать наш ресурс. Думаю, среди нашего сообщества найдется много собеседников. C уверенностью утверждаю, что здесь имеются С++ разработчики с огромным опытом написания веб-сервисов на прекрасном и могучем С++.

Comment: какая комната или сервер?) 
все у кого рейтинг >1k - создатели этого ресурса?))

Comment: Нет, это не так. Комната, сервер - читайте блог http://blog.hashcode.ru/ . В блоге появляются все новые фичи данного проекта!

Comment: В скором будущем у нас на форуме появится прямая возможность общения через IRC.

Comment: Извините, но где ссылка на форум? не могу найти %)

Comment: Это и есть форум, т.е. http://hashcode.ru/ ;)

Comment: а вы не планируете сделать возможность отправки сообщений пользователям? а то иногда надоедает общаться с помощью комментариев :-D

Comment: Если у вас есть комментарии по сайту, Вы всегда можете оставить отзыв (ссылка находится в подвале сайта).